# How to use multiple knowledgeBaseId using Dialogflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

We are building a bot using dialogflow in nodejs, we want to know how to utilize multiple knowledgeBase while detecting Intent?

```
knowledgeBaseFullName = 'unique_id_of_knowledgebase'; // if you don't know how to find it, let me know :)

const knowledgeBasePath = knowbase.knowledgeBasePath(
    projectId,
    knowledgeBaseFullName
);
... // omitted middle code
const request = {
    session: sessionPath,
    queryInput: {
       text: {
           // The query to send to the dialogflow agent
           text: 'Hey, how are you doing?',
           // The language used by the client (en-US)
           languageCode: 'en-US',
       },
    },
    queryParams: {
          knowledgeBaseNames: [knowledgeBasePath]
    },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer, today is very very strange for me!

```
queryParams: {
    knowledgeBaseNames: ['projects/project-id/knowledgeBases/k-b-id','projects/project-id/knowledgeBases/k-b-id-2']
},
```